# Field exchange symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, field-theory

I have a pheraps stupid doubt regarding the existence of a symmetry. Consider a theory such as:

$$\mathcal{L}= \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\psi)^2+\phi^2\psi^2$$

With some real scalar fields. This lagrangian seems invariant under the tranformation:
$$\phi\rightarrow\psi,\qquad \psi\rightarrow\phi$$

This symmetry should also leave invariant the path integral.

My question is:

Suppose I have some operators
$$O_A=\phi\partial\psi-\psi\partial\phi$$
And
$$O_S=\phi\psi$$
Then is it possible to say that for vacuum correlators:
$$\langle 0\rvert O_A O_S\rvert 0\rangle=0$$ (or really any product with an odd number of $O_A$)
due to the symmetry above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vacuum correlators, of course. Consider plain integrals, before you generalize to functional ones,
$$
\langle f(x,y)\rangle= {\int\!\!dxdy~~ e^{-S(x,y)} f(x,y) \over \int\!\!dxdy~~ e^{-S(x,y)} },
$$
which vanish for $S(x,y)=S(y,x)$ and $f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$. Functional integrals of this type also vanish.